# Providing host files for docker machine with cloud provider

Tags: docker, docker-machine

If I'm using a remote cloud provider to host my docker machine, obviously I can't mount local volumes when running on cloud provided machines. What are my options for providing files at runtime? Does docker / machine provide any mechanism or should I be looking to push/pull to the docker machine or via a 3rd party file host?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is command `cp`. This is only way I know.

Copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem

Usage:

```
docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:PATH LOCALPATH|-
docker cp [OPTIONS] LOCALPATH|- CONTAINER:PATH
```